# Change the name of an app and migrate users

Tags: facebook, migration, facebook-apps

We have already a Facebook app using a specific domain name, namespace and visual name.
Board decided to change the name of the company, so we created a new app with the new name and new logo (etc.), how is it possible to migrate current users from old app to new?

Comment: Why would want to you do that? Why not just keep using the same app ID but change the content on the website and rename the app?

Comment: We tried doing that but it seems changing the "Display Name" doesn't change the users from seeing the old name when they are asked to share their details.

Answer (score 0):

You can obviously carry your old database across and let your previous users know of this change, but it is my belief that they would have to re-accept your app the first time they re-enter as Facebook would treat them as first time users.

Comment: Thank you Chris, I did not find the option to do this carry :(

Comment: By this I mean the database you had for your original app with userId's can be transferred from one app to the other.

Comment: Ok but do you know where i can do it ? is there somewhere in app admin where i can put new app id ?

Comment: The app id should be contained in code for your app.  You just need to swap the new id generated by Facebook for the old one.